# Comparar Dados do banco com resultado de AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

Faço uma requisição *AJAX* na `view` e uma pesquisa no *banco de dados*. Preciso comparar o resultados das duas e se um item for igual quero imprimir um resultado em uma `div`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {number: 48996713742},
        url: 'http://consultaoperadora1.telein.com.br/sistema/consulta_json.php?chave=' + senha +'&numero=' + number,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#content").html('');
        },
        success: function(data){
            var item = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#operadora').val(item.operadora);
            var operadora = item.operadora;
            console.log(item.operadora);
            phone = '(' + item.numero.substr(0, 2)+ ') ' + item.numero.substr(2, 5) + '-' + item.numero.substr(6,4);
            $('#content').append('\
                Número: '+ phone +'\
                Operadora: '+ operadora +'\
            ')

            @if(count($operators) > 0)
                @foreach($operators as $item)
                    @if($item->code == 'operadora')
                        $('#content').append(item.operadora)
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        }
    })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mano, não mistura desse jeito. Cada coisa no seu lugar...

Comment: Tô tentando, mas não sei como fazer

Comment: Você tem que comparar na rota onde faz o AJAX, no PHP.